# Two apparently identical queries using the same query plan, return different number of rows from an index scan

Tags: sql-server

I'm trying to understand why two queries using the same query plan, querying the same data, are behaving differently.

I was investigating the following query.

```
select T1.id, T2.Num 
from DB1.dbo.Table1 T1, DB1.dbo.Table2 T2 
where T1.DataDate = (select MAX(datadate) from DB1.dbo.Table1)
and T1.col2 = T2.col2 
and T1.col3  = 1 
and T2.col4 = 'A string' 
order by T1.id
```

Table1 is a heap with a single unique nonclustered index based on datadate, col2 and col3. The table has 150 million rows. The datadate column is a char(8) nullable column holding date values (yyyymmdd).

Table2 has around 300 rows.

The data in both tables has been static for the last few weeks. Stats have not been updated on either table for the last few days.

The issue centred around the subquery

```
(select MAX(datadate) from DB1.dbo.Table1)
```

which generates the following branch in the estimated query plan.

[Query Plan for large index scan](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KJnZ2.png)

This includes an index scan against the Table1 unique index. This passes all 150 million rows through to the next step (Distribute & Gather Streams). This version of the query took on average 45 seconds to complete.

I found that by adding a "IS NOT NULL" where clause as follows -

```
 (select MAX(datadate) from DB1.dbo.Table1 where datadate is null)
```

the query plan branch changed to the one shown in the link below. With an index seek against the Table1 unique index, passing a single row through to the "Top" step, with no intermediate Distribute or Gather stream steps. This version of the query completed in around 1 second.

[Query plan for index seek](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WPPbb.png)

So far so good. I can't say I understand exactly why the addition of the IS NOT NULL clause should have such a dramatic effect, but the query plans of the two different queries made sense to me.

Where I started to get confused, was when I tried repeatedly running the original query, just to confirm that the difference in duration between the two queries was not a fluke. What I found was that running the first version of the query (without the "IS NOT NULL" where clause) took over 40 seconds most times it ran, but every so often it would complete in under 1 second.

When I looked at the actual execution plan XML of the two runs of the same query (the "1 second version" and the "45 second version") I found the following.

The two queries were using the same query plan. 
I based this on the QueryPlanHash

QueryHash="0xCF7F3761DC77476E" QueryPlanHash="0x55A6B0D6E3D73607"
QueryHash="0xCF7F3761DC77476E" QueryPlanHash="0x55A6B0D6E3D73607"

However, when it came to the number of rows read by the index scan against the Table1 unique index, the query that took over 40 seconds read all 150 million rows.

[Actual Execution Plan XML - long duration query](https://i.stack.imgur.com/58zJf.png)

However the query that took 1 second only scanned a fraction of those rows.

[Actual Execution Plan XML - short duration query](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kKL0I.png)

This can also be seen in the graphical actual execution plan, with the long duration query passing 150 million rows from the index scan

[Graphical Actual Execution Plan - long duration query](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lJgDA.png)

And the "1 second version" passing just 14,000 rows from the index scan.

[Graphical Actual Execution Plan - short duration query](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fh6Wj.png)

This different behaviour explained the difference in the duration of the two queries.

So after this very long explanation, my question is:

How can two identical queries, using the same query plan, querying the same data (no updates to the tables involved between the two queries, no update stats between the two queries) return a different number of rows from the same index scan?

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was replaced with the *proper* ANSI `JOIN` syntax in the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (**more than 25 years** ago) and its use is discouraged

Comment: @marc_s - This is client code that I picked up using xEvents - I don't like the separated list of tables either, but in testing I didn't find it to have any effect on the resulting query plan so I left it in as it is the code being used.

Comment: Even though they have the same plan hashes, do the queries run with the same @@OPTIONS applied? There are several @@OPTIONS values that can affect plan execution. The most common problem causing "it runs bad in the app but well in SSMS" is ARITHABORT which defaults to OFF in most client libraries but ON in SSMS.

Comment: @AlwaysLearning As far as I can tell, from looking at the Actual Execution Plan XML, the options are the same for both queries, namely           <StatementSetOptions ANSI_NULLS="true" ANSI_PADDING="true" ANSI_WARNINGS="true" ARITHABORT="true" CONCAT_NULL_YIELDS_NULL="true" 
    NUMERIC_ROUNDABORT="false" QUOTED_IDENTIFIER="true" />

Comment: In fact it looks to me as though this might be an example of the following issue identified by Paul White - [link](https://www.sql.kiwi/2012/05/parallel-row-goals-gone-rogue.html). If I understand correctly - the Top operator can issue a "close" call when it thinks it has the rows it needs, but the parallel threads sometimes respond to this and sometimes don't. When they don't, they'll read the whole 150 million rows. This accounts for the difference in behaviour